# Secure Dual-Boot Walkthrough

Tags: uefi

I have been looking at dual-booting Ubuntu x64 over an existing UEFI Installation of Windows x64 on an ASUS laptop.

I can't find any decent walkthroughs on how to dual-boot with UEFI without disabling it.  I understand I will have to Shrink Volume on Windows etc. but where do I go from there? Is it a special image or will the Ubuntu x64 Rolling-release work?

Any guidance is appreciated, but I can't find a solid walk-through on this.  Many thanks!

Comment: This might better fit a another community. See for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/927924/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode#928101

Comment: Good call.  I just figured the user group here is wider - I am also not stuck on Ubuntu, but I was ready that they had a Shim Key or something and a few other distros (not Arch for example, but Red Hat does).